# I can't create a new button for my program and I don't know how to open a new window with that button

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*

main_window=Tk()
main_window.geometry('500x500')

def first_window():
    def second_window():
        main_window_label.destroy()
        main_window_button.destroy()
        second_window_label=Label(main_window,text='choose on section',font=('Times_New_Roman',25))
        second_window_label.pack()
        def back():
            second_window_label.destroy()
            second_window_button.destroy()
            first_window()
        second_window_button=Button(main_window,text='back',font=('Times_New_Roman',25),command=back,activebackground='red')
        second_window_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
     
    main_window_label=Label(main_window,text='welcometo our _______',font=('Times_New_Roman',25))
    main_window_label.pack()
    main_window_button=Button(main_window,text='next',font=('Times_New_Roman',25),command=second_window,activebackground='blue')
    main_window_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)



first_window()
main_window.mainloop()
```

I wanted one more button to appear in the second window and this button would open a new window. But I can't do it

Comment: Please share with us what is going wrong. What have you tried? Which errors are you receiving? How is the result not what you want?

Comment: You must use Toplevel() for second window

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

> I wanted one more button to appear in the second window and this
> button would open a new window. But I can't do it.

Just add `new_window = Toplevel()` on to the `second_window()` function.

Modified code:

```
from tkinter import*

main_window=Tk()
main_window.geometry('500x500')

def first_window():
    def second_window():                  
        new_window = Toplevel()
        new_window.title('New Window')
        second_window_label=Label(new_window,text='choose on section',font=('Times_New_Roman',25))
        second_window_label.pack()
        def back():            
            new_window.destroy()
            
        second_window_button=Button(new_window,text='back',font=('Times_New_Roman',25),command=back,activebackground='red')
        second_window_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
     
    main_window_label=Label(main_window,text='welcometo our _______',font=('Times_New_Roman',25))
    main_window_label.pack()
    main_window_button=Button(main_window,text='next',font=('Times_New_Roman',25),
                              command=second_window,activebackground='blue')
    main_window_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)



first_window()
main_window.mainloop()
```

Output main window:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Output first and second window:

[image]

You can modified to suit your need.